# option to add new ZSQL method is not shown in Zope 2.13.6

Tags: zope

When I installed ZSQL explicitly for Zope 2.13.6, I thought it will be easier to connect RDBMS. But option for adding ZSQL method from ZMI (management interface) is not shown. I have used build out to install ZSQL package. As this package comes as default in prior releases, i do not have to face this problem. Also no specific information is found for installing ZSQL package in Zope. 
Kindly give the solution. 
Regards,

CPK

Answer (score 1):

"Works for me"::

```
$ /opt/Python-2.7.0/bin/virtualenv --no-site-packages /tmp/zsql
New python executable in /tmp/zsql/bin/python
Installing setuptools............................done.
$ /tmp/zsql/bin/easy_install Zope2==2.13.6 Products.ZSQLMethods==2.13.4
...
Finished processing dependencies for Products.ZSQLMethods==2.13.4
$ /tmp/zsql/bin/mkzopeinstance -u admin:123 -d /tmp/zsqlinst
$ /tmp/zsqlinst/bin/zopectl fg
...
2011-07-05 11:35:53 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests
```

The "Z SQL Method" option is in the ZMI add list.  Selecting it shows a page which says,
"There are no SQL database connections. You need to add a Zope SQL database connection before
you can create a Zope SQL Method."  After adding a package for my SQL backend, e.g.:

```
$ /tmp/zsql/bin/easy_install Products.ZMySQLDA
...
Finished processing dependencies for Products.ZMySQLDA
```

and restarting Zope, I added a "Z MySQL Database Connection", and was then able to add
and successfully test a "Z SQL Method" against the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Add eggs in the product: Products.ZSQLMethods, but a warning, I think you still get errors: (I'm also trying to solve, no new post here.

Cleber J Santos

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Zope Database Adapter installed, and possibly a python DBAPI module, before that option is available.

My preference is to use SQLAlchemyDA for the database adapter and an appropriate DBAPI (I use cx_oracle for Oracle and psycopg2 for PostGreSQL, but SQLAlchemyDA supports most relational databases)